# After finishing building a site on localhost, how do I transfer everything to a client's server?

Tags: migration, localhost, xampp

I have installed XAMPP to build a site on localhost. After I finish, how do I transfer everything efficiently to, say, a client's server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and [Backing Up Your Database « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database) and [How to Move WordPress Blog to New Domain or Location  »  My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/10/01/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/) and possibly [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

Deleted this added link as it advocates using a texteditor to change URLs in the dump; that will break serialized data. Use the SQL statements in How to Move WordPress Blog to New Domain or Location above. See [Why is my database import losing text widget data?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9076/why-is-my-database-import-losing-text-widget-data)

Comment: Thank you. Through that last link, I found exactly what I was looking for: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/hosting/migrating-a-wordpress-site-from-a-local-server-to-production/

Comment: @John: Thank Rarst, it was his suggestion in chat :)

Comment: @hakre: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/hosting/migrating-wordpress-across-hosts-servers-and-urls/ advocates using a text editor to change URLs; that will break serialized data.